# Where can I get the Android ICS menu button icon?

Tags: android, menu, icons, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I take two days searching the ICS menu's icon, but I don't find it in anyplace. It's the icon that appear on the photo's right corner, I've downloaded the ics's icon set but nothing, it's not include. Do you have it? Where can I download it? Or I have to make the icon? Thanks a lot!

[image: http://developer.android.com/design/media/iconography_actionbar_colors.png]

Comment: Try use android asset studio http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find those icon's from your Android SDK directory. for example if you have your Android SDK in **D:** means, you can find from this path **D:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable-mdpi**  . and then you can add ICS icon's like this in your xml file `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"`.
hope this one may helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The icon was in the Res folder, but It doesn't appear in the android:drawable, I think that's because my application min sdk is 8, and althought the target SDK is ICS, it doesn't let me access to all resources.

Comment: Buni@ yeah . you are correct. if you want to use some inaccessible  icons means, better you just copy those icons and rename it and you can use it. simple.